# grep -- handle text within quotes

Tags: linux, grep

I have a line of text that I'm using grep to see if the letter `d` exists.  Here is an example of what is going on:

**Returns 1, this is correct:**

```
echo d file='hello world' | grep -c -w d
```

**Returns 0, this is correct:**

```
echo file='hello world' | grep -c -w d
```

**Returns 1, this is correct:**

```
echo d file='hello world d' | grep -c -w d
```

**Returns 1 -- should return 0:**

```
echo file='hello world d' | grep -c -w d
```

I need it to ignore the data inside the single quotes.  Is `grep` the right tool to use here or is there something else that might help?

Comment: Do quoted strings ever span lines?  Are there any other quoting characters?  Can there be strings with an embedded quotes?

Comment: It's always one line and only single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `sed` to remove all text inside quotes, and then do a `grep` on the output of `sed`. Something like this:

```
echo "d 'hi there'" | sed -r "s|'[^']*'||g" | grep -c -w d
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output through a tool to get rid of anything you don't want, for example `sed`:

```
echo d file='hello world' | sed -e "s:'[^']*'::g" | grep -c -w d
```

This reads: replace (`s`) anything which matches the regular expression (delimited with `:`) with the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info you provided, this should work:

grep -c -E "^[^']*?d.*?'.*?'"

```
%> cat blah.sh

echo d file=\'hello world\' | grep -c -E "^[^']*?d.*?'.*?'"
echo file=\'hello world\' | grep -c -E "^[^']*?d.*?'.*?'"
echo d file=\'hello world d\' | grep -c -E "^[^']*?d.*?'.*?'"
echo file=\'hello world d\' | grep -c -E "^[^']*?d.*?'.*?'"

%> ./blah.sh
1
0
1
0
```